# jquery load function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jquery load function to load a 3D model converted to a .DAE file into a target div when a button is pressed. However, when the button is pressed loads of numbers appear on the screen relating to the file, rather than the model...

[Here is a screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAIAJ.png)

If it isnt possible to do this, I was also wondering if it is possible to use the jquery load function to simply replace the model shown in the centre of the page when the buttons are clicked, as show in the screenshot?

Any help is greately apperiated. The code i have can be seen below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#LBC').click(function() {
    $('#target').load('bloodexternalcontent.DAE');
});



});
</script>

<title>Visualising Cells</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<script>
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
</script>

<script>

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;


var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.01, 500 );
camera.position.z = 0.16;
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
scene.add(camera);


var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width,height); 
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.render(scene,camera);
renderer.setClearColor("rgb(181,181,181)");

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
        scene.add(light);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(0, 0, 0.14);
        scene.add(light);



var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.load('egg2.DAE', function (collada) {

            object = collada.scene;
            object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.y = 0;
            object.position.z = 0;
            object.updateMatrix();
            scene.add(object);
            }
            );



document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
console.log("Up Arrow Pressed");
console.log(camera.position.z);
if (event.keyCode == 38) {

    if (camera.position.z >= 0.1) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 0.01;

    }

}

else if (event.keyCode == 40) {

    console.log("Down Arrow Pressed")

    if (camera.position.z < 0.2) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.01;
    }

    }
}, true);

render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

object.rotation.x += 0.0;
object.rotation.y += 0.0;


renderer.render(scene, camera);
controls.update();
        };
        render();

</script>


<div class="float-btn">
<button type="button" id="LBC">Load Red Blood Cell</button>
<button type="button" id="LEC">Load Egg Cell</button>
</div>

<div class="float-txt">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 18px">
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
<h1>Visualising Microscopic Cells</h1>
</div>

<div class="instructions">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 16px">
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
<h2>Instructions</h2>
</div>

<div class="instruction-txt">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 14px">
<p><u>Zoom In:</u> <strong>Up Arrow</strong> <br><u>Zoom Out:</u> <strong>Down Arrow</strong></br></p>
</div>

<div class="Model-Location" id="target">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would it normally work if you took the content of that .dae file and just stuck it in a div, without ajax ?

Comment: @adeneo I've got one of the models on the page as shown in the screenshot, i tried using jquery to allow me to switch between the two models when pressing the buttons in the bottom left corner of the page. If their is an alternative way to achieve this then im open to it but in regards to your suggestion, im unsure how to try it.

Comment: @adeneo Is the only way to load the model (.DAE file) through jquery to put it inside a div? If so, is there an alternative method to load the model into the centre of the page much like the screenshot and switch between the two using the buttons?

Comment: I don't really know anything about .DAE files or this renderer but it looks like the `loader.load` part of the script is the key. I think putting something similar with the other DAE file name in your `$('#LBC').click()` might do the trick

Comment: @DonovanM By that do you mean put 'loader.load' in the place of 'target' or add something to the click function?

Comment: @DonovanM Similarly, is there a selector that would load the model into the centre of the page, rather than putting it inside the div? Basically i just want to open the website and click on the two buttons to switch between the model (.DAE file) displayed in the centre of the page, much like the screenshot in my question.

Comment: Yes, I mean to put the `loader.load` where `target` currently is. Unfortunately I don't know enough about these libraries to answer the second question.

Comment: @DonovanM I've tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I've posted a solution using the approach @DonovanM suggests. Essentially, you load the relevant .dae data into the Collada loader object which is then re-added to the scene.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the model shown in the centre of the page by loading the .dae data into a configurable `THREE.ColladaLoader()` object in much the same way that `loader.load` is used in your original code.

In the example below, click events are bound to the two buttons. These fire a function that removes the current model. The relevant .dae file is then loaded and the required model is added to the scene. (Note that I've left HTML issues in your markup untouched, e.g. unclosed divs.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <title>Visualising Cells</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

        <script>
            var myModel; // used to reference the most recently-loaded model

            $(document).ready(function() {
                // when the page has loaded, add click functions to the two buttons
                $("#LBC").click(function() {
                    toggleModel("bloodexternalcontent");
                });

                $("#LEC").click(function() {
                    toggleModel("egg2");
                });
            });

            function toggleModel(modelName) {
                // remove the existing model from the scene
                scene.remove(myModel);
                // add the chosen model
                loadModel(modelName);
            }

            function loadModel(modelName) {
                // add the specified model
                loader.load(modelName+'.DAE', function (collada) {
                    myModel = collada.scene;
                    myModel.position.x = 0;
                    myModel.position.y = 0;
                    myModel.position.z = 0;
                    myModel.updateMatrix();
                    scene.add(myModel);                
                });
            }

            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.01, 500 );
            camera.position.z = 0.16;
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.y = 0;
            scene.add(camera);

            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

            var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(width,height); 
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            renderer.render(scene,camera);
            renderer.setClearColor("rgb(181,181,181)");

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
                    light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
                    scene.add(light);

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
                    light.position.set(0, 0, 0.14);
                    scene.add(light);

            var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

            // load the default model
            loadModel("egg2");

            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {        
                console.log(camera.position.z);
                if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                    // don't scroll the window        
                    console.log("Up Arrow Pressed");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (camera.position.z >= 0.1) {
                        camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 0.01;
                    }

                }
                else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                    // don't scroll the window
                    event.preventDefault();
                    console.log("Down Arrow Pressed")

                    if (camera.position.z < 0.2) {
                        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.01;
                    }

                    }
                }, true);

            render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);

                // object.rotation.x += 0.0;
                // object.rotation.y += 0.0;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);            
                // controls.update();
            };

            controls.addEventListener('change', render );

            render();
        </script>

        <div class="float-btn">
            <button type="button" id="LBC">Load Red Blood Cell</button>
            <button type="button" id="LEC">Load Egg Cell</button>
        </div>

        <div class="float-txt">
            <div style="color:#000000">
              <div style="font-family: Arial">
                 <div style="font-size: 18px">
                     <div style="text-decoration: underline">
                         <h1>Visualising Microscopic Cells</h1>
                    </div>

                 <div class="instructions">
                     <div style="color:#000000">
                         <div style="font-family: Arial">
                             <div style="font-size: 16px">
                                <div style="text-decoration: underline">
                                     <h2>Instructions</h2>
                                 </div>

                 <div class="instruction-txt">
                    <div style="color:#000000">
                        <div style="font-family: Arial">
                            <div style="font-size: 14px">
                                <p><u>Zoom In:</u> <strong>Up Arrow</strong> <br><u>Zoom Out:</u> <strong>Down Arrow</strong></br></p>
                            </div>

                 <div class="Model-Location" id="target">
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou for working out a solution, I really apperciate it. The only issue now is getting the OrbitControls to work, or is there an alternative way to add a set rotation like I did previously?

Comment: I've updated the code to address this by using the OrbitControls: you should find that the up/down arrow keys now have an effect. The main changes are to disable controls.update() in the render() function, add in the controls event listener, and to stop the up/down keys from also scrolling the window (which caused problems for me testing on a laptop). You'll likely need to tweak the code to meet your needs, but it should at least be functional. This is as far as I can take it.

Comment: I've copied the code you updated and it doesn't work, the 3D model is not longer on the page.

Comment: It works for me, but I've edited it again as I noticed a separate issue (disabling key presses other than up/down), so please try once more. If no better, does your browser console show any errors?

Comment: I've copied the re-edited code again, but the model is still not visible on the page. The browser conole shows these errors: 
TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor
VisualisingCells.html:58:28
TypeError: loader is undefined
 VisualisingCells.html:37:17

Comment: The first error means you're not including OrbitControls.js in your code. Please check you're using all the code in my answer, which is working for me.

Comment: I've copied the entire answer above and pasted it into the html file. It's line 58 that it doesn't like
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
Could it have anything to do with the location of the OrbitControls.js file within my documents?

Comment: Yes, if the path in line 12 ('js/controls/OrbitControls.js') doesn't match the actual location of the file that'll cause the same issue, but in that case there should be a corresponding error in the console.

Comment: their is only one error that the console is picking up, it highlights line 58 of the code which is:

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

then says THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor.

Comment: If your OrbitControls.js file is in the right place (matches the path given in the code) then I can't see what the issue is, sorry.

Comment: I've just researched it and on an alternative stackoverflow post is says to only use controls.addEventListener('change', render ); when there is no requestAnimationFrame. Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: I've got it to work, but for some reason the model disappears when i click to rotate it

Comment: Re: your previous comment, there is no reason why the 'not a constructor' error would have anything to do with adding the event listener, as it clearly occurs earlier on when attempting to create a new OrbitControls object. I don't have any more time to spend on this, there's some difference between your code/setup and mine, as the code in the answer works for me as written.

Comment: Alright, thankyou for all of your help, it lets me zoom in and out with the mouse but does not let me rotate the model, i will look into it.